# Getting a line from a PlainDocument and the associated AttributeSet

Tags: java, swing, attributes, document

I would like to know how to retrieve a single line from a PlainDocument object and how to retrieve the corresponding AttributeSet of that line. I know the PlainDocument does not maintain any character level attributes but each line can be tagged.

I am using a PlainDocument object and append strings by using the

```
insertString(int offs, String str,  AttributeSet a)
```

method. As AttributeSet I pass a SimpleAttributeSet like this:

```
SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet();
sas.addAttribute("Test", "More Test");
```

So far I have alway retrieved the Strings(/lines) like this:

```
int start = doc.getDefaultRootElement().getElement(0).getStartOffset();
int end = doc.getDefaultRootElement().getElement(0).getEndOffset();

doc.getText(start, end-start-1));
```

However I am unable to get the attributes like this:

```
doc.getDefaultRootElement().getElement(0).getAttributes().getAttribute("Test");
```

and

```
doc.getDefaultRootElement().getElement(0).getAttributes().getAttributeCount()
```

only returns 0.

Am I making a more elemental mistake here?

**Edit:**
What I have found out so far is that

> Line to offset, and offset to line translations can be quickly performed using the default root element.

from the Oracle [DOC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/PlainDocument.html) probaly only meant the functions:

```
int start = doc.getDefaultRootElement().getElement(0).getStartOffset();
int end = doc.getDefaultRootElement().getElement(0).getEndOffset();

line = doc.getText(start, end-start-1));
```

as well as:

```
getDefaultRootElement().getElementIndex(offset)
```

Aside of that I also figured out that one could use the functions

```
doc.putProperty(LineNumber, "LineTag");
doc.getProperty(LineNumber);
```

to implicitly store a tag for each line. Those are of course just key/value pairs one can use to store pretty much everything. And the translation too would have to be done separately. So that is probably not what is meant by

> each line can be tagged with an arbitrary set of attributes

Comment: Have you found anything out? I am also very interested in saving attributes for a plain document.